# How to convert select that renders partial onchange from rails 6 to rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

**Beware i work with haml not erb !**

In my rails 6 app i have a select.
If i change the select the content of the page is changed.

The view is as follows:

```
:javascript
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript") }
  });

  $.fn.subSelectWithAjax = function() {
  var that = this;
  var jpeg_id = "#{@jpeg.id}";

  this.change(function() {
  $.post(that.attr('rel'), {id: that.val(), jpeg_id: jpeg_id }, null, "script");
  });
  }

  });


%h1.text-center
  = "Example select"

%br
= select(:label, :id, Label.all.map {|u| [u.description, u.id]}.push(["Unknown", 0]),{ selected: 0 }, rel: "update_label_content")
%br
%br

#gallery
  =render partial: 'shared/gallery' , locals: {image_objects: @image_objects, jpeg: @jpeg, current_label: 0 }

:javascript
  $("#label_id").subSelectWithAjax();
```

I know the code is a bit ugly, but the last line makes that a change in the select calls the subSelectWithAjax. This function posts to the "update_label_content" in the controller.

The controller code looks like:

```
  def update_label_content
    @jpeg = Jpeg.find(params[:jpeg_id])
    if params[:id].to_i == 0
      @image_objects = @jpeg.image_objects.where("label_id=0 or label_id is null")
    else
      @image_objects = @jpeg.image_objects.where(label_id: params[:id])
    end
  end
```

This function renders the view (update_label_content.js.haml) that looks like:

```
$("#gallery").html("");
$('#gallery').append("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'shared/gallery' , locals: {image_objects: @image_objects, jpeg: @jpeg }) }");
```

The _gallery.html.haml looks like this:

There is some lightbox-gallery stuff in this code. You should ignore this !

```
  %div{ class: "lightbox-gallery"}
    .container
      .row.photos
        -for obj in image_objects
          - if obj.mask_image.present?
            .col-sm-6.col-md-2.text-center.item
              %a{ href: obj.mask_image.url,  "data-toggle": :lightbox, "data-type": "image", "data-gallery": "example-gallery", class: "img-fluid" }
                = image_tag(obj.mask_image, height: "200", class: "draggable", id: obj.id )
```

**How to port this code to rails 7 ?**

Answer (score 0):

So this is where i came out.

First i had to read about hotwire. This consists of 2 parts, turbo and stimulus. You should read the documentation of [hotwire](https://hotwired.dev/) first.

I made the answer in steps:

**Step 1**

I made a controler file in the javascript/controller directory called label_bin_controller.js:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="label-bin"
export default class extends Controller {


  connect() {
    console.log("is it connecting ?");
  }
}
```

**Step 2**

From the old view i:

1. removed all the javacode
2. added a div around the code with a data-controller label-bin.
3. added a hidden file to get the jpeg_id (this could be done differently)
4. removed the "rel" and added a data-action to the select

```
-# change 2
%div{ "data-controller": "label-bin" }   
  %h1.text-center
    = "Example select"
  -# change 3
  %input{ type: :hidden, id: :jpeg_id, value: @jpeg.id }
  %br
  -# change 4
    = select(:label, :id, Label.all.map {|u| [u.description, u.id]}.push(["Unknown", 0]),{ selected: 0 }, { "data-action": "label-bin#change" })
  %br
  %br

  #gallery
    =render partial: 'shared/gallery' , locals: {image_objects: @image_objects, jpeg: @jpeg, current_label: 0 }
```

In order to test we can load the view and in the console browser debug console  there shoud be the message "is it connecting ?" from the label_bin_controller.js. One thing i found odd is that you should use label-bin in your code but the file is called label_bin.

**Step 3**

If we have the controller connected we can add the change event:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="label-bin"
export default class extends Controller {


  connect() {
    console.log("is it connecting ?");
  }

  change(event) {
    console.log("Change");
    var label_id = document.getElementById("label_id").value;
    var jpeg_id = document.getElementById("jpeg_id").value;
    const frame = document.getElementById('image_objects');
    frame.src="update_label_content?jpeg_id=" + jpeg_id + "&id=" + label_id;
    frame.reload();
  }

}
```

If we reload the page in the browser and change the select the change should be triggered in the stimulus controller. You should see the console message in the browser and also receive a call to the rails controller on the server side. (get request)

**Step 4**

We have to add a line to controller action to render with turbo_stream:

```
  def update_label_content
    @jpeg = Jpeg.find(params[:jpeg_id])
    if params[:id].to_i == 0
      @image_objects = @jpeg.image_objects.where("label_id=0 or label_id is null")
    else
      @image_objects = @jpeg.image_objects.where(label_id: params[:id])
    end
    # added line
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(:image_objects, partial: "shared/gallery", locals: { image_objects: @image_objects })
  end
```

**Step 5**

You have to embed your _gallery partial in a turbo-frame.
As said above there is some lightbox-gallery and draggable code in this, please ignore this !

```
  %turbo-frame{ id: :image_objects }
    %div{ class: "lightbox-gallery"}
      .container
        .row.photos
          -for obj in image_objects
            - if obj.mask_image.present?
              .col-sm-6.col-md-2.text-center.item
                %a{ href: obj.mask_image.url,  "data-toggle": :lightbox, "data-type": "image", "data-gallery": "example-gallery", class: "img-fluid" }
                  = image_tag(obj.mask_image, height: "200", class: "draggable", id: obj.id )
```

I documented this for myself. I hope other can benefit from this. I tried to make it as simple as possible, but could have created some errors in the proces.